# Javascript: Toggle Auto Scrolling Up or Down

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, scroll

I have a page containing a push button and two radio buttons placed near the bottom of the page. My goal is to create a function triggered by the push button that scrolls the page up or down, depending on whether or not the two radio buttons are active. Once users select the two radio buttons, the push button will then scroll to the top of the page. The snippet provided has the code that I have so far. Once the two radio buttons are activated, I want the 'scroll down' code to no longer work and just have the button move the user to the top of the page. It works as intended in this example and in Firefox, but chrome and edge have trouble interpreting it. In these browsers, the page will scroll to the bottom when it is at the top, which makes sense considering that the 'scroll-down' code is placed at the beginning of the function. How can the code be optimized/separated so that it works as intended without the two window.scrollTo's interacting with each other?

```js
function Push() {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    if(mode1.checked) {
        if(mode2.checked) {
            window.scrollTo({top: 0});
}}}
```

```html
<style>
  html {
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>

<body>

</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

<div align="center">
  <button id="button01" onclick="Push()">Push</button>
</div>

</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

<div align="center">
  <form id="mode">
    <label><input type="radio" id="mode1"/></label>
    <label><input type="radio" id="mode2"/></label>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it written; when both radios are checked and the Push() function is called, the page will scroll to the bottom first and then to the top. It happens so fast you don't notice it (at least I don't), but the code says that is happening.

**EDIT:** I did prove that this is the case by testing in codepen by setting a breakpoint here: `window.scrollTo({top: 0});`. When it breaks here it has scrolled to the bottom and then when I step into the next function call it scrolls to the top.

I would change the Push() function like this:

```
    function Push() {
        if(mode1.checked && mode2.checked) {
            window.scrollTo({top: 0});
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        }
    }
```

Doing so results in only one scroll action firing (up or down).

**It also appears that IE does not support using `scrollTo` with options as you do here: `window.scrollTo({top: 0});`. May be best to use `window.scrollTo(0,0)`. I used that in the snippet below.**
This may be your Chrome and Edge issue as well depending on what version of each you are testing on. See this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-scroll-methods

One last notable observation: You currently have no way to "uncheck" the radio buttons due to the designed functionality of radio buttons. I assume you know that and is not an issue, but thought I would mention it. Using checkboxes or custom checkboxes would allow you to accomplish this if needed. There are other ways to accomplish this as well.

```js
function Push() {
    if(mode1.checked && mode2.checked) {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    } else {
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
}
```

```css
html {
    height: 500px;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<body>

</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

<div align="center">
  <button id="button01" onclick="Push()">Push</button>
</div>

</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

<div align="center">
  <form id="mode">
    <label><input type="radio" id="mode1"/></label>
    <label><input type="radio" id="mode2"/></label>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll give this a try. I left out a smooth scroll for the sake of keeping the snippet simple. My actual site will include one.